# What is the complex partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{z^2 - z + 1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-fractions

I need this result to compute a residue. I haven't been successful so far.

What I have tried: 
I have tried decomposing $\frac{1}{z^2 - z + 1} = \frac{A + Bi}{z - \omega} + \frac{C + Di}{z + \omega}$ where $\omega$ is the cube root of unity. I didn't get anything from this method.

Answer (score 4):

By the quadratic formula the zeroes of $z^2-z+1$ are $\frac12(1\pm i\sqrt3)$, the two non-real cube roots of $1$. Let $\omega=\frac12(1+ i\sqrt3)$; the other root is $\overline\omega$, the complex conjugate of $\omega$. Then $z^2-z+1=$  $(z-\omega)(z-\overline\omega)$.

Now just set up the usual partial fractions computation:

$$\frac1{z^2-z+1}=\frac{u}{z-\omega}+\frac{v}{z-\overline\omega}\;,$$ so $u(z-\overline\omega)+v(z-\omega)=1$, and you have the system $$\left\{\begin{align*}&u+v=0\\&u\overline\omega+v\omega=-1\;.\end{align*}\right.$$ That ought to be pretty straightforward to solve.

Comment: +1 If it doesn't feel like cheating, you can also find the values of $u$ and $v$ by using l'Hospital's rule:
$$ u=\lim_{z\to\omega}\frac{z-\omega}{z^2-z+1}=\lim_{z\to\omega}\frac1{2z-1}\ldots$$

Comment: @Jyrki: Neat. I don’t think that I’ve seen anyone do that before.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1** Given that the degree of the polynomial is $2$, it is fundamental that

$$z^2-z+1=(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)$$

**Hint 2**

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&\alpha\beta=1\\
&\alpha+\beta=1
\end{align*}\right.$$

(Why?)

**Hint 3**

$$\frac{1}{(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)}= \frac{A}{(z-\alpha)}+\frac{B}{(z-\beta)}$$

for some $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate starting point:

$$
1-z+z^2 = \frac{z^3+1}{z+1}.
$$